# Join two tables based on table_1 column value to table_2 column name that matches?

Tags: php, mysql, join

Is it possible to join 2 tables together on the basis of table 1 column value equaling table_2 column name?

```
table_1     table_2
-----    -------------
| A |    | 1 | 2 | 3 |
|---|    |-----------|
| 1 |    | Q | W | E |
-----    -------------
```

Desired result is:

```
Select A from table_1 join table_2 WHERE table_1 A = table_2 column name.

Result:
1Q
```

I am using PHP, sorry for the poor psudo SQL, I honestly have no idea how to word it. Thank you for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0):

You want SQL where you use a value from one column as the name of another column.  You Can't Do That™. In pure SQL queries the names of tables and columns must be literals (using the lingo of php style languages.

You probably can get the result you need by reading your tables into RAM with your php program, then programming your table-to-table correlation.

Comment: ok thanks. is it possible to query for results in one query. then use the result of a column value to be the column name of the next queries column? say query 1 result = $result. then do `select $result from table2`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(table_1.A,"",table_2.1) as RESULT
FROM table_1 
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.A = table_2.1
```